# How can /proc/sys values be changed at boot (sysctl.conf does this on normal Linuxes)?

Tags: system, 9.0-pie, kernel, init.d, omnirom

How can `/proc/sys` values be changed at boot?

`sysctl.conf` doesn't exist on Android and echoing values to the `proc` files isn't persistent.

Answer (score 4):

Use `init`'s `write` [command](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md#commands) in `/init.rc` or any other `.rc` file. You may also create your own:

```
# /system/etc/init/custom.rc

on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    write /proc/sys/kernel/hostname MyDroid
```

Set permissions and reboot device.

```
~# chown 0.0 /system/etc/init/custom.rc
~# chmod 0644 /system/etc/init/custom.rc
~# chcon u:object_r:system_file:s0 /system/etc/init/custom.rc
```

You may also use some early [trigger](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md#triggers) like `on init` or `on boot` but your value may get overwritten by some later trigger.

Also some values aren't allowed by SELinux to be written by `init`. E.g. `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` and `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio` are writable only by `vold`. In this case you can use  `exec` command which allows changing SELinux label before command execution.

```
# /data/sysctl.conf

kernel.hostname=MyDroid
vm.dirty_ratio=20
```

```
# /system/etc/init/custom.rc

on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    exec u:r:magisk:s0 -- /system/bin/sysctl -p /data/sysctl.conf
```

<sup>* `sysctl` is `toybox` applet. Or you may use `busybox`.</sup>

For other options see [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/213623/218526). Some apps may also provide similar functionality but I never used one.