# How do I prevent overwriting of sysctl variables?

Tags: system, ipv6

Android 10.

Trying to disable ipv6 (yes, I know the second line below appears redundant).

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/disable_ipv6
```

The values stay as long as I have wifi turned off:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/disable_ipv6 
1
```

But as soon as I turn wifi on, something changes (only) the wlan0 value back to 0:

```
# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/wlan0/disable_ipv6 
0
```

If I change it back to 1 again, it gets changed back to 0 within a few seconds (and in Settings / About phone, I can actually see the ipv6 addresses return). Does anyone know what causes this (and how I can prevent it)?

Comment: I don't think that's the right way. you are trying to change on linux, but you forgot android. probably it's set by apn/wifi settings app

Comment: Results from searches for how to disab/e ipv6 for wireless networking in android all note that doing so requires root, and suggest the method above.

Comment: messing with runtime [linux](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217495) kernel parameters doesn't make sense to me on android. anyway that would be temporary only. I could only image some [build.prop](https://gist.github.com/eladkarako/55a8688fc469b9ea9b9e6f7cbf403df2) tweaks might work (can be done from [Magisk](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3789228)). but the proper way is imho from [android](https://www.cactusvpn.com/tutorials/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-android) framework side. kindly wait for better qualified response

Comment: Android uses the linux kernel sources (built with the ANDROID flag). Applications exist (and I have one) to apply kernel parameter changes on every reboot. The "android framework" link you provided (every VPN has a similar page) applies only to mobile data, and has no relevance whatsoever to wifi.